# Complex Core Data Migration with Multiple Mapping Models

Tags: core-data, core-data-migration

We have a very complex core data model with enough data to warrant multiple mapping models.  We are having problems understanding the requirements for creating the relationships that span mapping models.  The code below is our latest attempt where we try to look up the related object in the destination context and set the relationship.  Now we do realize that we don't need specific object types and relationship names, but we're just trying to get this working on a small scale with one entity before we tackle the other 300 relationships.  HELP!!!  Marcus Zarra where are you?  Anyone else have a suggestion?

[Link to picture of the Data Model](http://deepbluewebtech.com/dbwt-misc/Model.jpg)
Code to create relationships...

```
- (BOOL)createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:(NSManagedObject *)dInstance entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager error:(NSError **)error {

if ([mapping.name isEqualToString:@"ProductImageToProductImage"]) {

    [super createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:dInstance entityMapping:mapping manager:manager error:error];

    NSArray *sources = [manager sourceInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:mapping.name destinationInstances:@[dInstance]];
    NSArray *destinations = [manager destinationInstancesForEntityMappingNamed:@"ProductImageToProductImage" sourceInstances:sources];

    NSManagedObject *sourceObj = [[sources objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"product"];

    if (destinations.count == 1) {

        NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Product"];
        request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"xID = %@",[sourceObj valueForKey:@"xID"]];
        ;
        NSArray *result = [manager.destinationContext executeFetchRequest:request error:error];
        if (result.count > 0) {
            Product *destProduct = (Product *)[result objectAtIndex:0];
            [dInstance setValue:destProduct forKey:@"product"];
        }

    } else if (destinations.count > 1) {
        NSLog(@"multiple products for %@",sources);
    }
}

return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to forego NSMappingModel completely and do a manual migration. When merging or splitting entities, adding new default data et.c. I always find this to be the easiest route.

To migrate manually, you fetch each object from the source context in any order you like, then create destination objects as needed. It can be be quite repetitive code, but you can write it quickly and debug it easily.

Answer (score 0):

So in place of this:

```
        BOOL ok = [migrationManager migrateStoreFromURL:sourceStoreURL
                                               type:sourceStoreType
                                            options:sourceStoreOptions
                                   withMappingModel:mappingModel
                                   toDestinationURL:destinationStoreURL
                                    destinationType:destinationStoreType
                                 destinationOptions:destinationStoreOptions
                                              error:&error];
```

I would just manually fetch from the source and insert into the destination, then create all the relationships all via Core Data methods, then add the new store to the PSCoordinator using the new model?

Comment: Ok, this is a bit late, but was this a reply to my answer?